# Storing results locally with JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a page where user makes a selection and I update db with an AJAX call, however, I would like to show selection if the user decides to back-track. If I did this just using PHP I'd probably add the items id and corresponded selected values into an array. But in this project I am not refreshing the page, so my questions... is there a way to store that data somehow locally, perhaps using JS. Or I can build a string on my AJAX page and return it via JSON.

Just looking for ideas on how to go about it.

BTW I am not using HTML5 in this project...

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly, why not just create a stack of selections:

```
var selections = [];

function makeSelection(_selection) {
    selections.push(_selection);

    ... ajax
}

function getLastSelection() {
    if (selections.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return selections[selections.length - 1];
}

function getSelections() {
    var out = '';
    var ct = selections.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ct; ++i) {
        out += (out == '' ? '' : ', ') + selections[i];
    }
return out;
}
```

Added a few functions to show how you can view / get selections.
Now you will have a local copy of where the user is (and has visited) for the current session.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a database to store variables and get them with PHP? and why don't you use HMTL5 because then you can use localStorage it's an awesome feature :)